# Calculate worth of inventory using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a website using Django and Python3 where users can add there MTG cards to their inventory. I have two tables, `inventory_cards` - 12,000 Rows - that holds the users inventory data and `pricing_cards` - 65,000 rows - that holds the pricing data for each card.

`inventory_cards` table contains `user_id`, `card_id`, `nonfoil`, `foil`

`pricing_cards` tables contains `card_id`, `date`, `nonfoil`, `foil`

I am trying to work out the total worth of a users inventory, however my code is either slow or super heavy on the database.

**method 1:**

The method takes around 6 minutes but only hits the database twice. With this data being displayed of a website, it is not viable to have the page take over 6 minutes to load.

```py
user_inventory = list(inventory_cards.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values_list('card_id', 'nonfoil', 'foil'))
pricing = list(pricing_cards.objects.order_by('card_id', '-date').distinct('card_id').values_list('card_id', 'nonfoil', 'foil'))

combined_list = [x + y[1:] for x in user_inventory for y in pricing if x[0] == y[0]]
for i in combined_list:
    inventory_value = Decimal(inventory_value) + ((Decimal(i[1]) * Decimal(i[3])) + (Decimal(i[2]) * Decimal(i[4])))
```

**method 2:**

The method takes around 15 seconds but the database shows over 25,00 transactions. This is still too long for the page to load, and can imagine the strain on the database with multiple users.

```py
user_inventory = inventory_cards.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values('card_id', 'nonfoil', 'foil')

for i in user_inventory:
    nonfoil_value = i['nonfoil'] * float(pricing_cards.objects.filter(card_id=i['card_id']).values_list('nonfoil').get()[0])
    foil_value = i['foil'] * float(pricing_cards.objects.filter(card_id=i['card_id']).values_list('foil').get()[0])
    inventory_value = inventory_value + (nonfoil_value + foil_value)
```

is there a better way to perform this calculation? is there python package I can install to perform this calculation better.

Comment: have you tried raw sql? I think with `INNER JOIN` and `SUM` you can do the whole thing in sql. I think that will run in less than a second.

Comment: if you can post a sql dump of your db and some test cases I (and others) can try to write a query

Comment: Thank you that put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

`bb1950328` pointed me in the right direction. The below code run a SQL query without using the Django models. The webpage loads almost instantly.

```py
with connections['default'].cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT SUM((inventory_cards.nonfoil * pricing_cards.nonfoil) + (inventory_cards.foil * pricing_cards.foil)) FROM inventory_cards INNER JOIN pricing_cards ON pricing_cards.card_id = inventory_cards.card_id WHERE inventory_cards.user_id = 3")
    inventory_value = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: don't forget to replace the hardcoded user id with a parameter ;)